# Function not applying to pandas dataframe properly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to count the matching objects (including duplicates) between two lists. In order to do so I have the following function:

```
def counter(row):
    return len([key for key, val in enumerate(row) if val in set(words)])
```

with words being the list of words. When I use this function with the loose string

```
lists = ['uno', 'dos', 'one', 'two', 'tres', 'quatro', 'yes', 'wooly', 'bully', 'watch', 'watch', 'come', 'come', 'watch', 'git', 'matty', 'told']
```

it works properly, yet when i apply it too the dataset with

```
df.apply(lambda row: counter(['Token']), axis=1)
```

or with

```
df['Token'] = df['Token'].map(counter)
```

the print output shows 0 for each row, while the values should be higher

Comment: Is your requirement to find the number of matching elements in a list and a column of data frame? In that scenario, you can pass the column values into the `counter` function.

Comment: how would i do that automatically, as i have 2600 columns

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
lst = ['uno', 'dos', 'one', 'two', 'tres', 'quatro', 'yes', 'wooly', 'bully', 'watch', 'watch', 'come', 'come', 'watch', 'git', 'matty', 'told']
lst = list(set(lst))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Token':['two', 'two', 'tres', 'tres', 'tres', 'quatro', 'quatro', 'quatro', 'quatro', 'yes', 'cool', 'car', 'cauterize']})
dct = df[df['Token'].isin(lst)]['Token'].value_counts().to_dict()
print(dct)

# {'quatro': 4, 'tres': 3, 'two': 2, 'yes': 1}
```

To match the dictionary with count to the dataframe you can do this:

```
df['Count'] = df['Token'].map(dct)
```